# Optimal referential 2d array?

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, optimization, actionscript

So, I'm creating a fairly basic overhead 2d game where users can "draw" a map. (Actually, they dont draw it, the manually input a list of x/y's, but the design aspect isnt important just now.)

When a new tile is added, that tile goes into an array of all tiles ingame.

The centrepoint is 0,0. Tiles can be added in all directions, so may be at 1,1 or 100,100 or -50,-50.

Sometimes I want to determine what tile is at a location. One (imho bad) way of doing this would be to get the x/y and loop through all tiles and check if they are that location.

The way I'm currently doing it is to have a seperate 2d array of null elements, and when a tile is added, its set at that array. (ie tilemap[10][10] = tile[100])
Of course, because the values can go negative, tilemap [0][0] is actually the -1000/-1000 tile. (chosen as an arbitrary limit)

Is there a better way of doing this? I feel like using a massive array of mostly empty objects could be more optimal.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution would be to keep an `Object` or `Dictionary` where the key is the x/y location.

So if you're adding a tile at `10,20`, you can store it in the Object like:

```
this.m_objs[tileX + "_" + tileY] = new Tile;
```

So if you want to check if something's at position `10,20` you can by using something like:

```
public function checkIfExists( x:int, y:int ):void
{
    return ( this.m_objs[x + "_" + y] != undefined );
}
```

Comment: Yep, a [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) is definitely the way to go here; although you could create a composite key as suggested; it is sometimes a better option to implement a [MulitMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), eg `tiles[x][y] = value;`, however this incurrs a penalty for adding new entries; eg: `if (tiles[x] == undefined) { tiles[x] = new Dictionary(); }`.

Comment: +1 for the dictionary suggestion. Dictionary object is the fastest object in the flash VM for this type of task. I've seen benchmarks where basically no matter the size of the list, the lookup time is almost instantaneous.

Comment: There is a small difference in speed between Dictionary and Object, but not as much as you think (just did a quick test to make sure: http://wonderfl.net/c/fB6U)

Answer (score 2):

I recomend using `Dictionary`, as searching in it much more faster then searching array. Judhing by possible coords -1000/-1000 it would be a great advantage!